# implementing compareTo() with generics and collection

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparable, generic-collections

i m working with collections and i cant figure this out... I want to override compareTO() method based on the "data" variable in the Node class.. so that i can invoke collection.sort() to sort the arraylist..

```
public class Node<E> implements Comparable<E>{

    public E data;
    public Node<E> next;

    public Node(){
        data=null;
        next=null;
    }

    public Node(E data1){
        data=data1;
    }

    public E getData(){
        return data;        
    }

    public Node<E> getNext(){
        return next;        
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(E o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And

```
public class Test { 
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Node> arr= new ArrayList<Node>();
        Node n1=new Node(1);
        Node n2=new Node(3);
        Node n3=new Node(4);
        Node n4=new Node(3);
        Node n5=new Node(6);
        Node n6=new Node(2);
        arr.add(n1);
        arr.add(n2);
        arr.add(n3);
        arr.add(n4);
        arr.add(n5);
        arr.add(n6);

        Collections.sort(arr);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your declaration looks odd to me. It would be odd to compare a `Node<Integer>` with an `Integer` for example - it would make more sense to compare a `Node<Integer>` with another `Node<Integer>` by comparing the integers within them.

You then need to constrain `E` such that you can compare the two data values.

So I suspect want:

```
public class Node<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<Node<E>> {
    ...
    public int compareTo(Node<E> node) {
        return data.compareTo(node.data);
    }
}
```

You could make this slightly more flexible at the cost of complexity, like this:

```
public class Node<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements Comparable<Node<E>>
```

(The body of the code would remain the same...)

Answer (score 0):

Basically the `E` element of your collection must also be comparable, which can be enforced in the following way:

```
public class Node<E extends Comparable<E> implements Comparable<Node<E>> {
```

Now in `compareTo()` you just compare your elements:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Node o) {
    return data.compareTo(o.data);
}
```

If your `Node` class accepts `null` data element, `compareTo()` must be implemented more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is basically delegating the comparison of the `Node` to the comparison of the runtime type `E`, so `E` itself should also implement `Comparable`. So I think you meant:

```
class Node<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparable<Node<E>> {

    private E data;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node<E> arg0) {        
        return arg0.data.compareTo(data);
    }

}
```

Also note that you should be comparing `Node` objects to `Node` objects, not `Node` objects to `E` objects.

**Side-note**: Your class members should be private. You even have getters, so why are they public?